# Can't test django autocomplete light view

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, django-urls, django-autocomplete-light

Just following the tutorial for django autocomplete and I'm a little worried because I already can't seem to figure out how to see the view for autocomplete despite writing the view and url for it. I'm trying to use autocomplete-light on 
admin for a model called KeywordInContext

urls.py:

`url(r'^keywordincontext-autocomplete/$', views.KeywordInContextAutocomplete.as_view(), name='keywordincontext-autocomplete',),`

views.py:

```
class KeywordInContextAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
   if not self.user.is_authenticated():
      return KeywordInContext.objects.none()
   qs = KeywordInContext.objects.all()
   if self.q:
      qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
   return qs
```

So I'm trying to just perform the "test view" part of the tutorial where I can see my autocomplete view and either I didn't configure something correctly or I didn't type in the url.

the url I attempt to use for the test is `/admin/gtr_site/keywordincontext/?q=7` the only part of tht url that I actually type in is ?q=7 for a random primary key... but any variant of this just loads the "KeywordsInContext" admin page.

What am I missing?

Comment: what tutorial are you following?

Comment: The one right on Django autocomplete light's website as a basic tutorial for using Django autocomplete light. Computer just crashed, thought I linked it.

Comment: Tutoral link: http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html